# why ::first-letter targets two first letters in some case and one in another?

Tags: html, css

The pseudo element `::first-letter` somehow style the first two letters in the paragraph which are "fi" as red instead of just one. **Why?**

```css
p::first-letter {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>first line</p>
```

Comment: here your code works well and only colors the first letter. maybe the problem is in another part of the code

Comment: strangely enough when I run code snippet here, it still shows "fi" as red. I wonder if this is only happening on my device.

Comment: Would be a Chrome bug, can repro in v.87 & v.89 (Big Sur) FF and Safari are ok.

Comment: Only one letter for me - mac + chrome

Comment: yeah thanks for that. I think it is the bug in Chrome. Cuz I tested on my phone, it works fine.

Comment: Seems like this problem happens only with the word "first", if you change "first line" to different words for example "last line" or something else, everything works fine.

Comment: yeah thats true. It also happens to letters such as "fl". But I think it has something to do with the version of Chrome that I have on my computer. Cuz I tested on Firefox and it works fine with no problems.

Comment: yeah this is an exceptional bug. Looks like it happens for `fi` because the `f` comes on top of letter `i`, when font-family is ariel. This doesn't happen when the font-family is something else like verdana.

Comment: Why isn't this exceptional error working for me (https://ibb.co/7JV6CXk) ? Maybe a browser version?

Comment: I am not sure too.

Comment: https://ibb.co/ZN0SPxF
here is what it looks like on mine.

Comment: Wonder if related to ligatures [The tittle of the i in many typefaces collides with the hood of the f when placed beside each other in a word, and are combined into a single glyph with the tittle absorbed into the f](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthographic_ligature#Stylistic_ligatures)

Comment: @Slick, what browser version?

Comment: If you compare the two screenshots, the issue lies in how the letter `f` is coming on top of letter `i`.

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov Version 86.0.4240.198 (Official Build) (x86_64)

Comment: @MartinSmith yeah that is very interesting you mentioned there.

Comment: @Slick, my version chrome 85.0.4183.121 (x64). Also checked for firefox. And it also works fine :)

Comment: @Mr_Green yeah buddy. I wonder if it mistakenly counts as one. haha

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov I also have no idea why it occurs too. Kinda strange to a beginner like me.

Comment: Running a bisect says the culprit is in [this changelog](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+log/01b0cb51ee2012b62ca3eeb48e0b1d63cc0d32a1..31b550f3f7863cd8248f6e37c339053d1cf26005), but I can't see a clear winner there, maybe [this CR](https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/chromium/src/+/1599062). But anyway, you should open a new issue at https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/ Also, setting `text-rendering: optimizeSpeed` makes the bug not trigger.